# swift init properties with self or not?

Tags: swift

I saw the code blow from swift 2.0 `init` method, Square is a subclass from `NamedShape`,
1. do i need to add a `self.property` or just use without `self` ?
2. Does it means properties before `super.init(name: name)` use `self`, and after not?

```
class Square : NamedShape {
    init(sideLength: Double, name: String) {
            self.sideLength = sideLength
            super.init(name: name)
            numberOfSides = 4 //Add self. or not
       }
}
```

and

```
init(sideLengt: Double, name: String) {
        sideLength = sideLengt //without self. , is it right?
        super.init(name: name)
        self.numberOfSides = 4
    }
```

Comment: you use **self** when the parameter variable is the same with the property value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use without self, but the field variable need be different than outside variable.

### Why?

Simple, variables in field is constant statement (`let`) `init(sideLength: Double, name: String)` `sideLenght` and `name` in this line are constants variables, because this you can't set new value for it.

ps. `let` in swift is same than `const` in other language

Ex.

[image: example why can't use same name without self]

The correct way to implement is with `self.`, because in this case we tell to compiler to set the variable outside in our class.

[image: example using variable with self]

Other example now setting variable without `self.`, look next image, we can use without self because it is outside variable.

[image: example using name without self]

Answer (score 1):

you use the keyword `self.name` when you are referring to the `name` is outside of the init. it's more to recognise what `name` you are referring to if you use the same argument "name" as your init parameter

here is an example

```
var name : String

init(name : String)//here we have the same name with the value above
{
self.name = name//self.name is the variable outside of the init and now we are making that value the same with the value used in init
}
```

Comment: whether you have inheritance or not if the value you want to change is outside of your init it is good to be named as self.valueName.. Keep in mind that if you have 1 variable with some name and an init parameter with the same name as the variable when you call that name inside of the init it will be of the parameters and not of the variable. thats why you use the self. on the other hand if you had different names then you wouldn't need the self and you could just say hey the name of my variable equals(=) the name of the parameter. no self... Self is also great for computed properties n switch